# Firebase Push Notification Internationally

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was able to integrate Firebase Push Notification into my android/ios app. My apps started getting international users and my question is Firebase Push Notification still works fine for them?

Is there anything i need to do to support Firebase Push Notification internationally?

Answer (score 1):

No extra implementation needed. The notifications target the devices. So long as the device meet the pre-requisite to receive a message (just a stable connection) then it should be able to receive the sent notifications.

Comment: Thanks, i think so. I just wanted to see if there is an explicit document about that or it is stated somewhere in the firebase dev documentation